# Unable to send JSON to rest end point in spring boot appilcation

Tags: java, json, spring, maven, spring-boot

I have to send JSON to the rest end service which is built using spring boot. I am not getting what I am doing wrong. Here is the code

```
@RestController public class EmailWithTemplate 
{
    @RequestMapping(value="/create-template",method=RequestMethod.GET)
    void CreateTemplate(@RequestBody EmailTemplate emailtemplate)
    {
        System.out.println(emailtemplate.getName());
    } 
}

public class EmailTemplate 
{
    private String name;
    private String body;
    //private String[] values;

    public void setName(String name)
    {
        this.name=name;
    }
    public String getName()
    {
        return name;
    }

    public void setBody(String body)
    {
        this.body=body;
    }
    public String getBody()
    {
        return body;
    }
}
```

Plus I have added jackson dependency also in the `pom.xml` file.

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-core-asl</artifactId>
        <version>1.9.13</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-mapper-asl</artifactId>
        <version>1.9.13</version>
    </dependency>
```

After starting the tomcat server when I hit:

> localhost:8080/create-template/{"name":"Test", "body":"Test body"}

This is shown in the browser:

> Whitelabel Error Page
>
> This application has no explicit mapping for /error, so you are seeing
>   this as a fallback.
>
> Fri Jan 29 01:58:00 IST 2016 There was an unexpected error (type=Not
>   Found, status=404). No message available

Comment: shouldn't your rest call be a POST method?

Comment: I tried POST also but the result is same

Comment: Rohan, Would you please post the the client code that actually calls your service? Also, it would really help to see the logs for your request/response pair.

Comment: Actually there is no client code. I myself is calling the service from browser after switching on the server. I am typing that json on web browser address.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically, your client code is appending the URL `localhost:8080/create-template/` with your JSON `{"name":"Test", "body":"Test body"}`. So, your the URL you are calling is `localhost:8080/create-template/{"name":"Test", "body":"Test body"}` which the server can't find because the server only knows the `localhost:8080/create-template/` resource. That's why you are getting the 404. The JSON needs to be part of the request body, not the request URL.

Also, your server is expecting a HTTP GET request. GET requests can't contain bodies. See: [HTTP GET with request body](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/978061/http-get-with-request-body)

You will need to do a HTTP POST method with the JSON as the body.

For example, you should send something like the following request:

```
POST http://localhost:8080/create-template/ HTTP/1.0
Content-Type: application/json

{
    "name":"Test",
    "body":"Test body"
}
```

Comment: so I do need a client method which call this service and I can't directly call the service from browser?

Comment: You can use either. I use DHC for Chrome to test out my JSON REST requests. Try putting the above request in there.

Comment: Yeah It is working on DHC but why not on browser web address? Is the answer is as you said server is not able to find as server only knows localhost:8080/create-template/

Comment: Are you doing a POST request from DHC or a GET request? Because from the browser, itself, it only implicitly does a GET request.

Comment: POST request. Actually I tried both GET and POST, and both gives the sam e result when accessing it through browser address.

Comment: I have one more question. Can i send html text through this json?

Comment: Are you asking if you can do something like putting raw HTML code into your JSON's `body` field?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/101939/discussion-between-rohan-singh-dhaka-and-jonathan-thoms).

Answer (score 1):

You must pass the JSON as POST body, not as URI path.

```
POST /create-template HTTP/1.0
Content-type: application/json

{"name": "Test", ...}
```

In jquery for example you'll have to call:

```
$.ajax({
   type: "POST",
   url: "http://localhost:8080/create-template",
   data: {name: "Test", ...},
});
```

Comment: Sorry I didn't get you. Can you explain a little more.

Comment: Convert your method to POST. Depending on what client you are using to hit the method you should have option to post a message body and setup a content-type. Please use those options. For postman, follow this url. https://www.getpostman.com/docs/requests